# Insert a lot of values into a table at the same time

Tags: python, sqlite

So basically, I have a project for school, and it requires me to write a program that will help two compatible persons meet. They have to answer different questions, then the program will compare the results.
So I have 21 questions I want to ask and I am trying to insert the 21 answers into a table in my database, but it is not working. With 9 questions, for example, it worked perfectly, here is the code:

```
import sqlite3


connexion = sqlite3.connect("Test Numero 106")
cur= connexion.cursor()


cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aaa(q1 TEXT, q2 TEXT, q3 TEXT, q4 TEXT, q5 TEXT, q6 TEXT, q7 TEXT, q8 TEXT, q9 TEXT, q10 TEXT, q11 TEXT, q12 TEXT, q13 TEXT, q14 TEXT, q15 TEXT, q16 TEXT, q17 TEXT, q18 TEXT, q19 TEXT, q20 TEXT, q21 TEXT);''')

ans=['A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A ', 'A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A', ' A','A']

if ans[1]=='A' and ans[2]=='A'and ans[3]=='A':
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO aaa (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20,q21) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', ans)


connexion.commit()
```

The list "ans"  is the answers inputted by a certain person and I'm trying to insert them in a certain table but they are not going in.
The software that I'm using "pyzo" is not telling me that there is an error in the code, but when I want to see the information in a certain table, it is empty.

Comment: Can you more clearly show what data you are trying to insert, and under which circumstances?

Comment: As you can see above I am trying to insert the elements of the list ans into the different  columns of my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python [sqlite docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) show that the second argument of the "execute" command needs to be a tuple. Can you try that and see if it works?

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO aaa (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20,q21) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', tuple(ans))
```

Comment: It worked and all, and I did many tests with fake answers. But when I change the name of my database to be able to have an empty one and insert actual answers from actual people, it doesn't work. Why?